# Should I not override -[UIViewConvtroller view]?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit, subclassing

I'm told not to override `-(UIView *)view` ever. Why not? I want to use a custom UIView subclass for my custom `UIViewController`. What's a better way to do so?

Comment: From [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2): `The UIView class is a key subclassing point for visual content that also requires user interactions. Although there are many good reasons to subclass UIView, it is recommended that you do so only when the basic UIView class or the standard system views do not provide the capabilities that you need. Subclassing requires more work on your part to implement the view and to tune its performance.`

Comment: @W'rkncacnter [Jacob](http://stackoverflow.com/users/220819/jacob-relkin)

Comment: Huh. In person, or here, or...? Sorry, I should have been more verbose -- I was interested in the background/rationale given (if there was any).

Comment: @W'rkncacnter - Over iMessage. :-) The rationale is because, and I quote, "there are side-effects, things that happen in UIVC's -view getter [... and] it's a breach of separation of concerns"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supposed to override `-view`. To accomplish the behavior you want, you can set up your view controller to load from a nib, or you can override the `-loadView` method. In the latter method you create whatever view you want and assign it to `self.view`.

Comment: +1 this is correct.  Additionally, by your question you (Moshe) are assuming that UIViewController only accesses its view via the `view` accessor method.  There is no guarantee that this is, was, or ever will be the case.  Thus, you should override the `loadView` method and then invoke `setView:`, so that the *underlying ivar* gets updated as well.  This guarantees then that the return value of `-view` will be consistent with the value in the backing ivar.

Comment: @DaveDeLong Ah, interesting point about the property access. I noticed that dot syntax refused to work with properties of my subclass, but using the overridden accessor method worked just fine. I guess that should have been a clue that something was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a nib or storyboard, simply set the root view's class to your new, custom `UIView` subclass. If you're not using a nib or storyboard, create your custom subclass in the `-loadView` method and set the view controller's `view` property to it. So, for example, if you had a custom `UIView` subclass named `MyView`, and you're creating it in code (not in a nib or storyboard), you'd do something like:

```
// This code sample assumes compiling with ARC
- (void)loadView
{
  // You should adjust the initial frame to be whatever's appropriate for this
  // view controller
  MyView* view = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 480)];
  [self setView:view];
}
```